# Chrome has access to the internet but the terminal and Firefox don't

Tags: ubuntu

Here what I have tried so far

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

with curl i get

```
curl -L http://www.google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
```

Only errors return when I type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

```
ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 98:e7:f4:8d:aa:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 55  bytes 6679 (6.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 165580  bytes 10379747 (10.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 165580  bytes 10379747 (10.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether cc:b0:da:7a:f8:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 43210  bytes 30354765 (30.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 38477  bytes 6969050 (6.9 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
    ping 8.8.8.8
    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=152 ms
    ^C
    --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 131.096/141.986/152.876/10.890 ms
```

I need to be able to access the internet, so what do I do to get this resolved?

Comment: just posted the step you could resolve your problem, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset the connection like this a re test, regards ;).

**1. We stop the card enp2s0**

**2. We set this card to the normal eth0 name default**

**3. you open internet on eth0**

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down  
sudo ip link set enp2s0 name eth0  
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Don't forget :

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I did that but when it finished rebooting the name changed back